# Google maps nearest points avoiding rivers / by itinerary

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Here is the deal : 
I need to find the closest points from  a point with a radius. 
For example, I need to get all the points in a 15 km radius. Thats easy with Google Maps Radius and all the examples on the web ;)

The problem is that from my office, a point is under the 15km radius, but it's on the other side of a river, so the car itinerary is about 30 km (using a bridge)!

Is there a simple solution to exclude those points or to calculate by intineraries ?
I supposed that I'll need to calculate all itineraries with returned points?  DirectionsRequest API?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

This mashup calculates driving routes in a given radius:

http://maps.forum.nu/gm_driving_radius.html

It is written with the API V2, but you can see how it's done.

note that when you say:

> I need to get all the points in a 15 km radius

...you're going to need a fairly big computer because the number of points is infinite. :-)

Answer (score 0):

- Use your 15km radius to refine the set of points.
- Use the [Distance Matrix Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix) to get the distance (or at least verify that it is reasonable).